# Forced capitalization on 'Sign in with Apple ID' prompt

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have a SwiftUI app with In App Purchases (IAP). As part of the IAP integration, I'm restoring previous purchases like this:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

This causes the system to show a *Sign in with Apple ID* prompt.

When you enter your id in the prompt's *Apple ID* field, it automatically capitalizes the first letter, as seen in the image below.

[image]

But the first letter of my Apple ID is *lowercase*.

The prompt does properly authenticate the user despite the capital letter, but I'm wondering why this is happening, as I assume this will be as confusing to my users as it was to me.

**Question:** Why is this thing capitalizing the first letter? Is there anything I can do to eliminate this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: That seems to be a quirk of iOS and is most definitely out of your control. Do note that email addresses are case insensitive. Anyway, you can disable the capitalisation by simply pressing the shift key on the software keyboard.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug report with Apple.